# Undefined behaviour in C++ asserts: accessing an invalid/null pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assert

Under Visual C++ 2010, the following snippet hides a dubious behaviour:

```
CObject* myObjectPtr = CObjectFactory::MakeAnObject();
assert( myObjectPtr->CanDoSomeWork() ); // myObjectPtr can be null due to logical errors
```

The following snippet, when placed in a function, did not trigger the assert when the pointer was NULL and the function returned immediately. Aside from an extra null pointer check obvious fix that anyone could suggest, what made the code behave in such a way? Shouldn't it usually complain about a memory access violation error even if that error occurs within an assert?

Comment: It it plain *undefined behaviour*. So anything could happen. Little point in trying to figure out why a particular "something" happened.

Comment: does `assert(true)` raises anything?

Comment: @Elazar, yes, it's running in Debug mode, asserts enabled and triggering for 'normal' situation.s

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks, I figured out it must've been undefined behaviour, but that particular point took me almost one month of searching in all the wrong places for the bug-source and I'd like to prevent even such clumsy mistakes from consuming more than a few minutes of debug time in the future (hence a motive to understand the cause better - VS2010 should have a particular implementation specification for this - may be different with other compilers).

Comment: What is CanDoSomeWork doing? Does it access CObject* members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myObjectPtr->CanDoSomeWork()
```

If CanDoSomeWork is not a virtual function then the compiler effectively rewrites this as 
    C_Object::CanDoSomeWork(myObjectPtr)

This doesn't involve any dereference of the object pointer at all so it won't crash or fail.
If it's a virtual function then it will likely crash as it will use the pointer to find the vtable.

Of course none of this is guaranteed by anything in the standard, it's all undefined behavour, however it explains what you are seeing happen.

Comment: Indeed, it was a non-virtual function - thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Formally, calling a non-static member function is a dereference of the object pointer. This results in undefined behavior. Whether it crashes or fails or seems to work as you expect depends on the compiler.

Comment: Yes indeed. It just happens to work like this on most compilers because it's the easiest and obvious way to implement it. Don't ever rely on it working like this!

Comment: @jcoder and even if it is compiled the obvious way, it won't segfault if the system has address 0 mapped to valid memory. Luckily most platforms don't in order to help the programmer catch errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
assert( myObjectPtr->CanDoSomeWork() );
```

will cause segfault(or UB) if `myObjectPtr` is NULL. Because `NULL->`* is undefined behavior.
 You should check if `myObjectPtr` is not a NULL pointer first.

```
assert (myObjectPtr != 0);
assert( myObjectPtr->CanDoSomeWork() .....);  // if you still need this (?)
```

Comment: yes, that was the obvious direction in the second I realized what was happening. But suppose you consider a pointer to be consistent and leave out the first assert, then the second assert might not crash the application as expected and hide a critical error altogether.

Comment: @teodron Yes exactly! It would have been nice if it segafault always. However it might not sometimes. Undefined behavior. So you should always check if your pointers are null before trying to deference them or indirect them.

Comment: Re: "segfault (or UB)" - formally, the behavior is undefined. That means only that the language definition doesn't tell you what happens; it doesn't mean that bad things must happen. Undefined behavior often manifests as a segfault, but it often does not.